# Android Java throws java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

When I call the REST API request I'm getting the following error message:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this happened due to some uncleared memory or cache of emulator. uninstall and rerun the program, this was fixed. also the rest api url must be https.